# Returning the lowest and highest value from my Local Storage json

Tags: javascript, json

```
var myjsonObj = '[{"location":"Helsinki", "temperature":4},
{"location":"Tokyo", "temperature":26}]';
var jsObj = JSON.parse(myjsonObj);

console.log(jsObj[0].location);
console.log(jsObj[0].temperature);
var observationsArray = [];

function init() {
  if (localStorage.observationsRecord) {
    observationsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.observationsRecord);
    for (var i = 0; i < observationsArray.length; i++) {
      prepareTableCell(observationsArray[i].location, observationsArray[i].temperature);
    }
  }
}

function onRegisterPressed() {
  var locationName = document.getElementById("location").value;
  var temperatureValue = document.getElementById("temperature").value;

  var stuObj = {
    location: locationName,
    temperature: temperatureValue
  };
  observationsArray.push(stuObj);

  localStorage.observationsRecord = JSON.stringify(observationsArray);

  prepareTableCell(locationName, temperatureValue);

  document.getElementById("location").value = "";

  document.getElementById("temperature").value = "";

}

function prepareTableCell(locationName, temperatureValue) {
  var table = document.getElementById("regtable");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var locationNameCell = row.insertCell(0);
  var temperatureValueCell = row.insertCell(1);

  locationNameCell.innerHTML = locationName;
  temperatureValueCell.innerHTML = temperatureValue;
  //firstNameCell.colSpan = 2;
```

}

Hello! I'm fairly new to web development and I've been following a guide on TechThree INFO's youtube channel. I have created an html form that submits the data to local storage. My next step is to display the lowest and highest temperatures from specified locations (in the past 24hrs) and also the current temperature from each location. I am currently clueless on how to display the data from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from your localStorage, you can use `localStorage.getItem(key)`

This will return your stringified JSON, so you'll need to parse that back to a JS Object.

`var observations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('observationsRecord'))`

Finally, you want to find highest and lowest temperatures.

```
var max = {
    location: '',
    temperature: 0
};
var min = {
    location: '',
    temperature: 0
};
for(var i = 0; i < observations.length; i++) {
    if(observations[i].temperature > max) {
        max.location = observations[i].location;
        max.temperature = observations[i].temperature;
    }
    if(observations[i].temperature < min) {
        max.location = observations[i].location;
        min.temperature = observations[i].temperature;
    }
}
```

Your highest temperature will be stored in max, and your lowest in min.

Hope this helps :)